# Cannot connect Power BI Desktop to Azure SQL!

Tags: azure-sql-database, connectivity

I'm trying to connect **Power BI Desktop** to **Azure SQL**, but I get "*We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided. Please try again.*"

it works fine if I try from **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio** I can connect with no problems with the same username/password

[image]

what I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get around this problem, notice that "Windows" is highlighted at the left of the dialog box. I clicked on Database, entered the database credentials, and then it worked.